# How to print specific section from a file if that section has the search keyword [BASH]

Tags: bash, shell, sh, scripting-language

Below is a snippet of a file named "books.info":

```
TITLE and AUTHOR                                                     ETEXT NO.

Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,      56900
 by Robert Lloyd Praeger

The Vicar of Morwenstow, by Sabine Baring-Gould                          56899
 [Subtitle: Being a Life of Robert Stephen Hawker, M.A.]

Raamatun tutkisteluja IV, mennessä Charles T. Russell                    56898
 [Subtitle: Harmagedonin taistelu]
 [Language: Finnish]

Tom Thatcher's Fortune, by Horatio Alger, Jr.                            56896

A Yankee Flier in the Far East, by Al Avery                              56895
 and George Rutherford Montgomery
 [Illustrator: Paul Laune]

Nancy Brandon's Mystery, by Lillian Garis                                56894

The Junior Classics, Volume 3: Tales from Greece and Rome, by Various    56887


~ ~ ~ ~ Posting Dates for the below eBooks:  1 Mar 2018 to 31 Mar 2018 ~ ~ ~ ~

TITLE and AUTHOR                                                     ETEXT NO.

The American Missionary, Volume 41, No. 1, January, 1887, by Various     56886

Morganin miljoonat, mennessä Sven Elvestad                               56885
 [Author a.k.a. Stein Riverton]
 [Subtitle: Salapoliisiromaani]
 [Language: Finnish]

"Trip to the Sunny South" in March, 1885, by L. S. D                     56884

Balaam and His Master, by Joel Chandler Harris                           56883
 [Subtitle: and Other Sketches and Stories]
```

I am trying to get the full info for a book if I search it by the author name.

Example1:

Search Keyword: **Al Avery**

Then return should be:

```
A Yankee Flier in the Far East, by Al Avery                              56895
 and George Rutherford Montgomery
 [Illustrator: Paul Laune]
```

Example2:

Search Keyword: **Robert Lloyd Praeger**

Then return should be:

```
Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,      56900
 by Robert Lloyd Praeger
```

**I have tried this:**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f books.info ]
then
    echo Please enter search keyword:
    read keyword
    command=$(grep -i "$keyword" books.info)
    echo $command
else
    echo books.info file is missing
fi
```

But it is not working exactly they way I want it to. Could anyone please help me with this?

---

**EDIT**

Updated the file structure after noticing a date line.
Tried:
    awk -v RS='\n\n' "/${keyword}/" infile
and:
    awk -v RS= -v keyword="$keyword" '$0 ~ keyword' file.txt
As suggested by the answers given below by @andlrc and @αғsнιη but it prints out a lot of other stuffs which are not related. My best guess is this line is breaking it:

```
~ ~ ~ ~ Posting Dates for the below eBooks:  1 Mar 2018 to 31 Mar 2018 ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Because the top of this line has 2 spaces and below one space, I think because of the top two spaces its not working properly.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `awk`, just define an empty line as **R**ecord **S**eparator and search for a string contains in any block:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' '/Al Avery/' infile
```

or set RS to empty string

```
awk '/Al Avery/' RS= infile
```

Once you need to get the block per user's input, then you could do:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' "/${keyword}/" infile
```

Note the use of double quotes instead of single-quotes which allows shell first do expand the variable then use it in *awk*.

---

to works with *keyword* if it was containing back-slash `\` or slash `/` and any, you could use awk as following (for the [`Shell (Bash, ksh, ksh93, mksh, zsh) which supports Pattern Substitution Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)):

```
PATTERN="${keyword//\\/\\\\}" awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["PATTERN"]' RS= infile
```

Comment: One can set `RS` to null with the same result: `awk -v RS= '/Al avery/' infile` See `man awk | awk '/RS is null/' RS=`

Comment: What would happen if the "keyword" variable contains a slash (`/`)?

Comment: **Down-voter**: don't be a silent, feel free to explain your downvote, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` command like below:-

```
 grep search_string -A n -B m file.extension
```

Here `-A` stand for after search line and `-B` stand for before search line so probably you can try with:-

```
command=$(grep -i -A 2 "$keyword" books.info)
```

Comment: that's true for "Example1", what about for Example2?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize awk and the Record Separator variable:

```
awk -v RS= -v keyword="$keyword" '$0 ~ keyword' file.txt
```

You can set variables for awk via the `-v` option; `-v name=val`. In your case we need to set the variable "keyword" to the value of the bash variable of the same name:

```
-v keyword="$keyword"
```

The awk script is:

```
$0 ~ keyword
```

which will match the whole block of content against the regex provided in the variable "keyword".

> If  RS is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a  plus one or more blank lines

Source: `$ man awk | awk '/RS is null/' RS=`

Comment: No need pass _keyword_ as awk's variable, we can use double quotes instead of single quotes for awk, then shell will do expansion on variable see my answer above.

Comment: @αғsнιη It would fail if the "keyword" contains a slash.

Comment: Correct, then what if in your was not containing back-slashes `"\"` :   )